# Закрытие модального окна при нажатии за его пределами

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Как можно определить, что человек нажал за пределы модального окна?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Советую убрать onclick из html. [Смотрим сюда](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/ms89duem/4/).

```
var modal = $("#modal"),
    login = $("#login");

function modal_open(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    modal.show().animate({opacity: 1}, 500 );
    login.show(500);
}
function modal_close(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    login.hide(500);
    modal.animate({opacity: 0}, 500 );
    setTimeout(function() { modal.hide(100) }, 500);
}
$('.animated').on('click', modal_open);
$('.glyphicon-remove').add('#modal').on('click', modal_close);
$('#login').on('click', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: вообще вы там видели jquery?

Comment: @binliz, вообще, да. И в песочнице выставлена версия 2.x (edge), и код сам за себя говорит, да и в тегах вопроса присутствует.

Comment: @Deonis прошу прощения за невнимательность

Comment: @binliz, ничего страшного.

Comment: @Deonis, спасибо большое, всё работает, очень благодарен вам за помощь!

Answer (score 2):

За пределами окна у вас есть серая область которая называется `#modal` на нее и вешайте свои события.