# Как сделать закрытие popup с помощью нажатия на overlay и общую кнопку закрытия?

Tags: javascript, popup

Мне необходимо, чтобы попап закрывалася

1. через кнопку закрытия - работает
2. через нажатую клавишу Esc - работает
3. через нажатие вне попапа, то есть на оверлей - не работает
   Многие советовали использовать общую кнопку для закрытия попапов ( у меня их 2 в проекте) и туда приделать закрытие через оверлей, пока все не получается и не пойму почему. [image: ошибки в консоли]
   Сроки,на котрые ругается браузер это как раз функция закрытия с описанием попап и где используется в открытии попапа

```
//функция открытия, если попап открыт, добавляем слушателя клавиатуры
function openPopup(popup) {
  popup.classList.add('popup_opened');
  document.addEventListener('keydown', closePopupEsc);
  popup.addEventListener('click', closePopupOverlay);
}

//функция закрытия, если попап закрыт, то удаляем слушателя клавиатуры
function closePopup(popup) {
  popup.classList.remove('popup_opened');
  document.removeEventListener('keydown', closePopupEsc);
  popup.removeEventListener('click', closePopupOverlay);
}


//новая функция для закрытия попапа при нажатии на оверлей (не работает)
function closePopupOverlay(evt) {
  if (evt.target === evt.currentTarget) {
    const popup = document.querySelector(selector.openPopup);
    closePopup(popup);
  }
}

//не работает
const closePopupButtons = document.querySelectorAll(selector.closePopupButton);
closePopupButtons.forEach((button) => {
  const popup = button.closest('.popup');
  button.addEventListener('click', () => { closePopup(popup); });
  popup.addEventListener('click', (evt) => { closePopupOverlay(evt); });
});

/*функция закрытия при нажатии на Esc: если значение нажатой кнопки Esc
то находим переменную с селектором открытого попапа и закрываем его*/
function closePopupEsc(evt) {
  if (evt.key === 'Escape') {
    const popup = document.querySelector(selector.popupOpen);
    closePopup(popup);
  }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Закрытие модального окна при нажатии за его приделами](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/353082/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0-%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8)

Answer (score 0):

Можно повесить так например на сам попап

```
popupEditProfile.addEventListener("click", (evt) => {
  if (evt.currentTarget === evt.target) {
    closePopup(popupEditProfile)
  }
})
```